# Typescript, create type: items array tuple from interface keys

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

It's easier to illustrate with code than to explain with words:

```
// `type` or `interface` doesn't matter to me.
interface MyCollection {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// The best and simplest solution I came up with.
type List<T> = Array<{ key: keyof T}>;

// I want `MyCollection` _keys_ to be present 
// as _values_ for `itemkey` prop in `myList` items.
const myList: List<MyCollection > = [
  {  itemkey: 'name' },
  {  itemkey: 'age' },
]
```

It's already not bad, because intellisense works and prevents from using wrong keys. But I need to guarantee that every key present in `MyCollection` is present in `myList`, i.e. current solution allows this:

```
const myList: List<MyCollection > = [
  {  itemkey: 'age' },
]
```

BONUS: would be the possibility to match `MyCollection` key type as well, e.g.:

```
type List<T> = Array<{ key: keyof T, value: T[keyof T] }>;

// !BAD `value` accepts either `number` or `string`, 
// but should only allow `number`.
const myList: List<MyCollection> = [
  {  key: 'age', value: 'should be number, not string' },
]
```

As far as I know there's no possibility to iterate an interface entries to do this.

What I tried is in the description of the problem. I explored mapped types, tuples, remapping via `as` and whatever else I could find on the web and in the docs.

Honestly, it's very confusing, a good old JS iteration declaring some kind of static constrains would be way more simpler :D

Comment: You could create a type that generates all the possible permutations... but this wouldn't work for larger interfaces (5 keys is already 120 possibilities). Then you would need a helper function to do the inferencing and validate the given type...

Comment: I'd say you're looking for an "exhaustive array type" which TS doesn't directly support.  Various approaches are listed in the answers to the linked questions.